# how to take onlythe x and y from Point class

Tags: java

I have a variable private Point _centralStation which located in class that I called her City.
the user in the main class decides which value will be to the location of the centralStation.
So he put for example:
Point center = new Point(5,5) .
I want to create a method who called MoveCentralStation(int x, int y)
that moves the location from his last value to the new one, but
the new points have to be in the first quarter of the x,y axis. 
I mean x cannot be -4 for example.
let's say for the exmaple it was 5,5
and now the user entered  -4,5
how can I deal with the x and y new values sepertely?
Thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You have to explain yourself a little better. However, this is what I understood.
You have such a class:

```
class City{

private Point _centralStation;

public City(){
    this._centralStation = new Point(5,5);
    //the initialization you specified
}

public void moveCentralStation(int new_x, int new_y){
    //TODO exactly what you have to implement
}

public Point getCentralStation(){
    //since you are not implementing just getters and setters you rather do
    return new Point(_centralStation.x,_centralStation.y);
    //instead of return _centralStation [this is what we call defensive copies]
}
}
```

Well, somewhere in the code, a client would call

```
City c = new City();
c.moveCentralStation(x,y); //given x,y are variables in the client's context
```

And these are the requirements for the moveCentralStation(int x, int y) operation:

1. x coordinate shall be positive
2. y coordinate shall be positive

First of all I suggest you to follow style conventions on the way you code: use capital letters only for the class names. Let's jump into the real problem. 
We need to refine the above requirements to make a specific implementation compliant with them. They aren't clear enough. An example of refinining i may suggest is the following:

1. If x coordinate is less than zero, an IllegalArgumentException shall be thrown
2. If y coordinate is less than zero, an IllegalArgumentException shall be thrown

And that's very simple to implement:

```
public void moveCentralStation(int new_x, int new_y){
    if(new_x < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("x must be positive");
    if(new_y < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("y must be positive");
   _centralStation.x = new_x;
   _centralStation.y = new_y;
}
```

It's a good practice to set private fields only when they are all consistants.